# SQLite database in PIG

Tags: java, sqlite, apache-pig

How can I read data from a SQLite database using PIG? I think I can write a UDF to achieve that? I have a function like below I want to form UDF of it and read data from PIG.

```
public void sqlReader(String db,String tableName,String outFile) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException{
    Connection c = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+db);
      c.setAutoCommit(false);
      Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM "+tableName+";" );
      ResultSetMetaData rmd = rs.getMetaData();
      int columnNo = rmd.getColumnCount();
      StringBuilder column = new StringBuilder();
      while ( rs.next() ) {
          for(int i = 1; i<columnNo; i++){
              column.append(rs.getString(i)).append(",");                
          }
          column.append(rs.getString(columnNo));
          // return this column as a tuple
       }
       rs.close();
       stmt.close();
       c.close();
      
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    finally{
        c.close();
    }
}
```